# Failed to reading or Doing GoogleServicesJson file: MainActivity.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am new to xamarin, I was transferred to a project and I was compiled I get this error: Failed to reading or Doing GoogleServicesJson file: MainActivity.cs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#add-googleplayservices-json

Comment: I have already done all the steps and I still spew that error.